# Why the order of set in tuple is important?

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, olap-cube, ssas-2008

I was just going through the [MDX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216769%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) documentation.

One clause there I found a bit tricky, rather I did not understood it clearly, as follows

> > The order of tuples in a set is important; it affects, for example,
> >     the nesting order in an axis dimension. The first tuple represents the
> >     first, or outermost, dimension, the second tuple represents the next
> >     outermost dimension, and so on
>
> { (Time.[2nd half], Route.nonground.air), (Route.nonground.air,
>   Time.[2nd half]) }

Also, is it ok to use cross join in a tuple ?

```
(Time.[2nd half] * Route.nonground.air * Route.nonground.air * Time.[2nd half])
```

Can anyone elaborate this with a simple example ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 5):

The specification refers to the order of tuples within a set, not the order of hierarchies within the tuples of a set (which by the way must be the same across all tuples of the set, but that is not of concern for this part of the specification).

This is important, as mathematical sets do not have any specific order, i. e. mathematically the sets

```
{a, b, c}
```

and

```
{b, a, c}
```

are equal.

But as MDX is meant for reporting, where the display order in a report may be relevant, it is convenient that an MDX set always has a specific order. Another difference between mathematical sets and MDX sets is that MDX sets can have duplicates, while in the mathematical sense, one element is either contained or not contained in a set, but never contained multiple times.

And if you compare that to SQL, then SQL result sets are unordered by definition like mathematical sets, but may contain duplicate records. You can however, in some situations, get an SQL result set ordered, but have to request that by an explicit `ORDER BY` clause. And some SQL dialects do not allow ORDER BY e. g. in subselects, as these never are directly returned to the final user. Technically, the advantage of only guaranteeing a certain order of the result set if explicitly requested has the advantage that the optimizer has more freedom to build an efficient execution plan than if a specific order of the result had always to be delivered.